# Будет ли применено к элементу?

Tags: css

```
.nav .active {
  /* css */
}
```

будет ли применено к элементу с вот таким class:

```
class="nav active"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет. к элементу с class="nav active" нужно писать так:

```
.nav.active {} /* без пробела */
```

Comment: Это во всех версиях CSS или только в CSS3?

Comment: @2202100 во всех. Если будет интересно, посмотрите css selectors, там довольно большая спецификация возможных выборок.